# how can I tell when the user has finished editing a file in Paint.NET?

Tags: .net, windows, filesystemwatcher

I want to write a screenshot app that grabs a screen shot, saves it to a file, opens Paint.NET with that file, then uploads the edited file to a service when the user is finished editing the file in Paint.NET.

I have the other stuff sort of covered. How can I detect when the image is finished being edited in Paint.NET?

I'm using .NET 3.5, C#.

I can use a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to detect changes in a specific file.  But the first time a file changes does not necessarily indicate that Paint.NET is finished.  I can wait for Paint.NET to exit - I suppose by examining the list of processes in Windows and detecting when Paint.NET is no longer there.  But a user may finish editing a file without actually closing Paint.NET.

If I have to tell the user to close Paint.NET, to signal that the file is ready for upload, I guess I could do that.  But I'm hoping to avoid that sort of extra requirement.

If Paint.NET holds a file open for read while it is being edited, then I suppose I could try watching for *that*.  But how?  Maybe by polling, trying to open the file with [FileShare.None](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx).

Is there a better way?

---

**EDIT** - no, Paint.NET does not keep the file open, not even for reading.  I can open an image file no problem with FileShare.None, even while it is being displayed/edited by Paint.NET.  So that idea won't work.

---

Does Paint.NET have a Remoting interface, where I can interrogate it for which files it has open?  that would suit my purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling with this a little bit, I think UI Automation will satisfy. Using the [System.Windows.Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.aspx) classes that were new in .NET 3.0, I can inquire about the contents of other Windows on the machine, and I can find a windows for a given process ID.  So it's a matter of

- finding the PaintDotNet.exe process via a search in [System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocesses.aspx)
- obtaining the [AutomationElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.aspx) for the main window of the PaintDotNet app
- checking the ["name" property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.nameproperty.aspx) of that Window.
- when it changes from "myfile.jpg" to something else, then I know Paint.NET has 
  stopped editing the file.
- if I get a ElementNotAvailableException , that means Paint.NET has exited.

I haven't tested this very much, but, this code seems to work for my purposes:

```
public void Run()
{
    var shortFileName = Path.GetFileName(_filename);
    System.Console.WriteLine("Waiting for PDN to finish with {0}", shortFileName);

    var s= from p in Process.GetProcesses()
        where p.ProcessName.Contains("PaintDotNet.exe")
        select p;

    if (s.Count()==0)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("PDN is not running.");
        return;
    }

    var process = s.First();
    var window = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindChildByProcessId(process.Id);

    string name =
        window.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.NameProperty) as string;

    if (!name.StartsWith(shortFileName))
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("PDN appears to NOT be editing the file.");
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            int cycles = 0;
            do
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(800);
                name = window.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.NameProperty) as string;
                if (!name.StartsWith(shortFileName)) break;
                cycles++;
                System.Console.Write(".");
            } while (cycles < 24);

            if (!name.StartsWith(shortFileName))
                System.Console.WriteLine("PDN is done.");
            else
                System.Console.WriteLine("Timeout.");
        }
        catch (ElementNotAvailableException)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("PDN has exited.");
        }
    }
}
```

The `FindChildByProcessId` method is an extension method from [this blog post](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2009/06/introduction-to-ui-automation-with.html). It looks like this:

```
public static class AutomationExtensions
{
    public static AutomationElement FindChildByProcessId(this AutomationElement element, int pid)
    {
        var cond = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ProcessIdProperty, pid);
        var result = element.FindChildByCondition(cond);
        return result;
    }

    public static AutomationElement FindChildByCondition(this AutomationElement element, Condition cond)
    {
        var result = element.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, cond);
        return result;
    }
}
```

This seems a little unorthodox, but, it just works.  The trickiest part is the timing - you need to wait long enough to let the app start up, which can be 1 second or it could be 7 seconds. Then try to attach to it with the UIAutomation classes.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no there's no better way. Applications like Microsoft Outlook have the same problem when editing attachments. You can try to make a best-guess effort by taking an all-of-the-above approach.

For example, when your application becomes active again after shelling out to Paint.NET (or whatever editor they have associated) you can check to see if the file has changed and maybe prompt if they are done. If the process closes you can use that as a pretty sure sign that they're done and skip the prompt. If the file system watcher detects changes, you can queue those up until Paint.NET is no longer active, etc.

But many applications will not hold any kind of lock on a file while editing it. I am pretty sure Paint.NET does not. Applications like Office do and that's probably the reason why editing Word/Excel attachments from Outlook is a lot more reliable than plain text files.